# Brightness control in Windows 10 doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, brightness

I have installed Windows 10 on my [XMG Clevo Model P150HM](https://eurocom.com/ec/upgrade(2,277,0)CLEVO_P150HM_SAGER_NP8150) laptop and the brightness control does not work. Neither the buttons <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> / <kbd>F9</kbd> (those are the buttons with the brightness icons) nor the slider in Settings can change the brightness.

The Device Manager shows two "Base System Devices' with a yellow exclamation mark. Maybe this is related? Windows 10 can't find drivers for these devices.

I did observe the brightness to dim automatically when the battery was almost empty, so this does technically work. How can I make manual control work?

I found an [official driver download site](https://www.clevo.com.tw/en/e-services/download/ftpOut.asp?Lmodel=P15xHMx&ltype=9&submit=+GO+), but the drivers are very very old and for Windows 7. Should I try to use these?

Comment: Windows 7 drivers will not work in windows 10, they changed the driver model for windows 10, use windows update to see if any W10 drivers are offered.

Answer (score 1):

*The Device Manager shows two "Base System Device"s with a yellow exclamation mark.*

You need to find the Video driver for your laptop (and any other drivers). Go to the laptop manufacturer's Support Site and look for the Drivers.  You may need to update both BIOS and Chipset for Video to work.

Comment: That is hard to say whether you should use Windows 7 drivers. Go to the Microsoft download site, get the Windows 10 upgrade adviser. Run this and see if it finds issues.  The laptop may not be completely Windows 10 compliant

Comment: Isn't the Windows 10 upgrade advisor for users running Windows 7?

Comment: Yes.  Try running on the machine

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly. I'm not planning on installing Windows 7.

Comment: It will work on Windows 10 or 7. If Windows 10 is running - run it there